# I can't delete user authentication

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing a user crud and the last step is missing, which is to delete the user's authentication account, but I am not able to do that. What's going wrong?

code:

```
 deleteUserButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
     firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function(user){
            user.delete()
      })
})
```

Comment: You might want to add `catch` to your promise/`signInWithEmailAndPassword` to get/log potential errors. Tough, _I am not able to do that_ is not a very precise description.

Answer (score 0):

For delete the user you need to use this method

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.delete().then(function() {
  // User is deleted.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // if error occur
});
```